# SSH not working after reboot

Tags: debian, ssh, services, systemctl

I was looking on Google for a way to reboot my Debain server, I found the following [source](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/debian-linux/debian-restart-command/) and I typed:

`systemctl reboot`

After doing this, I can't SSH anymore to my Debian server. How can I enable SSH again?

When I try to SSH I get the following:

`ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Connection timed out`

**-edit-**

Fortunatly via Hetzner's console I can still access the server, I'm clueless however how to turn on SSH. I tried doing `sudo systemctl restart ssh` it doesn't seem to work and I still get the connection timed out.

**-edit-**

I believe `systemctl reboot` disabled networking on my server, and I can't seem to get it up with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`. The `journalctl -xe` shows: [image]

My apologies for the image, Hetzner's console isn't allowing me to copy text from their console.

When I do: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` I only see:

[image]

When I type `ip link show` the output is as following:

[image]

Comment: Does the server respond to ping? That's the first step. If it doesn't then the problem is with systemd. If it does respond to ping, then try nmap to see what services were started & are listening. It might be that the problem is with sshd -- which might still mean you are out of luck, but it might offer an unusual way to get a command line in the server.

Comment: Do you have physical or console access to this machine? If it's a cloud instance you might be able to pull up a cloud console and log in that way to troubleshoot ssh.

Comment: @d4n3sh edited my main original post.

Comment: I would suspect a network issue. Can you ping google ? (8.8.8.8) can you ping your host from home (this might be less révélant)

Comment: @Archemar when I `ping google.com` it says `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: @Archemar and when I `ping 8.8.8.8` it says `connect: Network is unreachable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like `systemctl reboot` had messed up my networking setting.

To get networking working again I did first `ifconfig -a` to find my ethernet interface, which in my case is `ens3`. Next, I checked `cat /etc/network/interfaces` this loads it's setting from the `*cfg` files `/etc/networking/interface.d/*cfg`. In my case, there was just a single `.cfg` file. Next, I did `nano /etc/networking/interface.d/50-cloud-init.cfg`and changed every `eth0` occurrence to `ens3`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the sshd daemon w/ `systemctl start sshd` inside a shell in your server. Also verify that the sshd service is **enabled** by sytemd.  Type in `systemctl is-enabled sshd.serive` to see if it's enabled.  if not, you can enable it w/ `systemctl enable sshd.service`.

Comment: The ssh service seems enabled and I still can't SSH into the server after typing `systemctl start sshd`.

Comment: are you typing these commands in your machine or into the server? if you can't ssh into your server from **your** machine. you have to tackle the problem **inside** your server.

Comment: I'm typing them in the console provided by Hetzner.

Comment: and your host is named ```example.com```? probably you have just to use the right hostname -- our hostname ;)

Comment: example.com is to hide my real host at this site. Of course I do use my real host and not example.com :)

Comment: okay :) just aking about it. i also can't think of an single point of failure from what you have discribe so far. can you ping your srv, what's w/ the firewall? can you ssh into another machine from your srv? can you ssh into localhost from your srv?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter to the similar issue. The problem for me was because I change IP IPv4 Method from auto to manual. I did not have a correct config. After switching back to auto, reconnect, and it worked.

just need the correct config for me.

Comment: This answer is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after rebooting via `sudo reboot`
command I couldn't connect via ssh. my default SSH port is set to 9011 and that rule was removed after rebooting. I used VNC to connect and added the port in firewall rules using `ufw allow 9011` and it worked